# Submitting a Form from index page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm Rails newbie.

How to make a form which allows user to choose a language(en,fr etc) through Radio buttons in Home#Index View to Submit to Home#Language action ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you got any code to start with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag language_path, :method => :post do %>
  <%= label_tag :language_english, 'English' %>
  <%= radio_button_tag :language, 'english' %>
  <%= label_tag :language_french, 'French' %>
  <%= radio_button_tag :language, 'french' %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Where `language_path` is the path defined in your `routes.rb`, such as

```
match "/home/language" => "home#language", :as => 'language'
```

Comment: `form_for` does not take a path as an argument, but a record. I guess you meant `form_tag`? How does this form get submitted?